# Choose Web.Config file based on Requesting URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

My problem: I have an ASP.net application that uses a Web.config file, connects to a database, and is hosted at `example1.com`.

I want to create another instance of the application at `example2.com`. The only thing that will change is the Web.config file (and also the database). The rest of the code will always be the same.

Is there a way to choose which Web.config file to use based on the URL requesting the application?

I know that you can have different versions when compiling the application (debug, release, etc). But this application would be compiled and deployed already.

I know I could choose a different connection string based on the URL, but the application requires that the Web.config file be unique for each domain it is installed under. I would not want to have one Web.config file with 1000 connection strings in it, but rather 1000 Web.config files.

Does anyone know if/how this is possible?

Comment: Do both of these instances share the same location on the file system?

Comment: Are both of these applications actually *the same instance* and just being accessed by different URLs?  Or are they actually separate instances?  (If the latter, then why can't the second instance just have its own config file?)

Comment: @David I think multiple instances point to same source, but different databases.

Comment: Same instance, different URL. Same location on the file system.

Comment: I don't think this can be done using the same instance. The application pool will be restarted when you change the web.config.

Comment: @pinoy_ISF is there anyway to have multiple instances share the same code? Without having to copy the same code to 1000 different folders?